# Emacs remembering compilation command and directory

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to force emacs to remember compilation command so after I restart it and run `M-x recompile` it will run the last compilation process instead of `make -k` in current dir?

Comment: That is what `M-x recompile` does by default.  Could you try starting Emacs with `-q` and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Maybe [smart-compile](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/smart-compile.el) can help you. It can customize your complie command.

Answer (score 1):

Use savehist-mode, so minibuffer history is saved when you exit emacs and restored in the next session:

```
(require 'savehist)
(savehist-mode 1)
(setq history-length 1000)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It stores minibuffer history, but `M-x recompile` still tries to run `make -k` I'm using GNU Emacs 24.3.1